React Routing location not found
I don't know why this happening but it is saying no routes matched for location '/'. As it can be seen in Header file that home component is there for this url.

for better understanding, here is the repo :
https://github.com/MohdZaid259/MegaBlog.git

@jabaa i changed the file format and attached the repo link. please help asap

No, sorry. My Node.js can't read jpeg, too. Maybe add it as text.

@jabaa I've pasted whole repo link

Questions on Stack Overflow have to be self-contained and must not depend on external resources. Post your [mcve] as text in your question and not behind a link.

have you tried adding index prop in <Route />?
<Route index element={<Home />} />

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/src/App.tsx#L19-L22
I cloned your repo and ran in local, didn't encounter the Router issue, <Home /> is render


Didn't work either

@MOHDZAID maybe try delete the node_modules folder and npm install once again
